# Find decomposed unicode characters to be replaced by precomposed equivalents

Tags: javascript, regex

Targeting `ECMAScript 2019` where we have quite decent unicode support. I'm creating a simple text viewer where I want to inform the user that a certain decomposed character could be converted into a precomposed one. How can I find these characters?

**An example.** Consider the letter below. First we have the decomposed version, then the precomposed.

- `ä` - `0061 0308` in UTF-16
- `ä` - `00E4` in UTF-16

Now, mixing these seemingly identical characters implies some problems. When the user searches for *"ä"* not all *expected* occurrences will be found, as [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/euJS8R/1) demonstrates:

[image: 3 matches?!]

Here we got **three** matches. Confusing! Similarly, searching this text for *"ä"* would only give one match.

**The question.** To help the user understand what's going on, I want to highlight any decomposed characters that have a suitable precomposed version. Thus I need to find the *start* and *end* of these character groups.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a letter + a diacritic mark pattern with the ECMAScript 2018+ compliant RegExp:

```js
const re = /\p{Alphabetic}\p{M}+/ug;
const matches = "ständig".matchAll(re); // With decomposed/multibyte char
console.log([...matches].map(x=>[x.index, x.index+x[0].length]))
// => [ [2,4] ]
```

Here,

- `\p{Alphabetic}` -  matches any letter
- `\p{M}+` - any one or more diacritic marks.

Comment: Interesting read ++ I was wondering..can the length be greater than 1?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Looks like the match object "length" property missed the diacritic, but the match length itself is correct. The decomposed char is actually of length 2, so the end of the match is at Index 4. Yes, the length can be more than 1 and 2, it depends on how many diacritics are used after the base letter. In Vietnamese, there are chars that  use two diacritics.

Comment: I suppose your regex would *find* the decomposed characters X and you would then use [X.normalize('NFC')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) to get the composed version Y? And then replace X with Y?

Comment: @l33t If you need to replace, yes, you could use `s.replace(/\p{Alphabetic}\p{M}+/ug, (x) => x.normalize('NFC'))`

Comment: That will probably suffice. Though, after such a replacement, is there any risk that some characters could look *totally* different?

Comment: @l33t I do not know what you mean. From what I know, multibyte and precomposed chars can differ in the way they are rendered in different fonts. And again from experience, I know that precomposed chars usually look better.